# C# sql server 2008 r2 insert stored procedure won't work

Tags: c#, stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2

i've got this stored procudure that won't work. If I try this query in the management studio with my parameters filled in it works, i can't see if i've done anything wrong in my code but i hope someone here does notice something i'm doing wrong

```
CREATE PROCEDURE new_project 
-- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
@proj_naam nvarchar = null,
@plaats nvarchar = null,
@opd_geef int = 0,
@status int = 0,
@proj_id int = 0  AS  BEGIN
-- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
-- interfering with SELECT statements.
SET NOCOUNT ON;

-- Insert statements for procedure here
INSERT INTO project (naam_project, plaats, opdrachtgeverZEEBREGTS_nr, status, project_NR)
VALUES (@proj_naam, @plaats, @opd_geef, @status, @proj_id)  END  GO
```

and c# code:

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection con;
            con = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection();
            con.ConnectionString = Global.ConnectionString_fileserver;
            con.Open();
            string stopro = "";
            switch (type)
            {
                case 1:
                    stopro = "new_project";
                    break;
                case 2:
                    stopro = "new_bedrijf";
                    break;
                case 3:
                    stopro = "new_persoon";
                    break;
            }
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(stopro, con);
            command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            switch (type)
            {
                case 1:
                    SqlParameter proj_naam = command.Parameters.Add("@proj_naam", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
                    SqlParameter plaats = command.Parameters.Add("@plaats", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
                    SqlParameter opdrachtgever = command.Parameters.Add("@opd_geef", SqlDbType.Int);
                    SqlParameter status = command.Parameters.Add("@status", SqlDbType.Int);
                    SqlParameter proj_id = command.Parameters.Add("@proj_id", SqlDbType.Int);
                    proj_naam.Value = tb_proj_projectnaam.Text; proj_naam.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
                    plaats.Value = tb_proj_plaats.Text; plaats.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
                    opdrachtgever.Value = cb_proj_opdrachtgever.SelectedValue; opdrachtgever.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
                    status.Value = cb_proj_status.SelectedValue; status.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
                    proj_id.Value = id; proj_id.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
                    break;  
            }  
            int nwok = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
```

So i hope someone can help thnx in advance!

Comment: Does it throw an specific error ?

Comment: Can you define "won't work"?  Does it give an error message, or not return anything? Does it actually get to the ExecuteNonQuery line, because it is after the break, but that just may have been because you snipped some code out.

Comment: no errors, the int nwok stores the number of rows affected, so if a row is added it will return 1, if not 0, and i'm only getting 0. And if I check my database the new row is not there. So it didnt do anything.

Comment: Also, I apologize but I just have to say the obvious because I've done this myself before. Are you sure you're on the right SQL Server? I can't tell you how many times I've executed against Dev but checked against Live.

Comment: @Chris Haas, haha no luckily this is not the case. This problem is now solved (thnx y'all) now i need to find why he keeps using the ID# from the last time a new record was added in stead of the next smallest non existing nr.. so I will have something to do this weekend :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i can see that if Case is not **1** in your switch case then the command instance never get those parameters so it wont work.

Comment: @Ardman it wasn't before the edit. so my answer was for that case. You can check his question's revisions

Comment: Is this not the right place for the break? at the and of the statement and before i define case 2: ? And I checked if case 1 was called with a messagebox and that also works fine.

Comment: @Daanvl: Yes, it is the right place to define a `break` statement.

Comment: @Daanvl: no your break statement is perfectly in right place.. you should check in debugger if correct values are being passed to parameter and Command instance is getting the parameters

Comment: @Shekhar_Pro i found this program anjlab sql profiler and got this:exec new_project @proj_naam=N'Daan',@plaats=N'tilburg',@opd_geef=4,@status=2,@proj_id=946 and some other line's, whats the N before the '' is that the problem or is it to define an NVARCHAR?

Comment: @Chris Haas only the first letter of the parameters where added, that was also the reason why it didnt show up in my program when checking if the record was in the database

Answer (score 3):

You have a `break` before your `int nwok = command.ExecuteNonQuery();`

**EDIT**

Not related to why your SPROC isn't executing but you've got `SET NOCOUNT ON` which will cause `-1` to be returned by `ExecuteNonQuery`. Are you running `SET NOCOUNT OFF` before the insert?

Comment: this is because after that there are a few more irrelevant cases that i cut out so the post doesnt get a mile long :P but i will chek if execute gets called nonetheless. edit: no, execute gets called just fine..

Comment: NOCOUNT ON was one of the reasons i didnt work, stupid autogenerated microsoft code.. the other was (i think) not defining a length for the NVARCHAR's

Answer (score 0):

Here you are testing the `type` in a `switch` statement:

```
switch (type)             
{                 
    case 1:                     
        stopro = "new_project";                     
        break;                 
    case 2:
        stopro = "new_bedrijf";                     
        break;
    // etc.
}
```

You then retest the `type` in another `switch` statement which is just overkill.  Move your parameters into the first `switch` statement and this may resolve your error.

```
switch (type)             
{                 
    case 1:                     
        stopro = "new_project";     
        SqlParameter proj_naam = command.Parameters.Add("@proj_naam", SqlDbType.NVarChar);                     
        SqlParameter plaats = command.Parameters.Add("@plaats", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
        SqlParameter opdrachtgever = command.Parameters.Add("@opd_geef", SqlDbType.Int); 
        SqlParameter status = command.Parameters.Add("@status", SqlDbType.Int); 
        SqlParameter proj_id = command.Parameters.Add("@proj_id", SqlDbType.Int);
        proj_naam.Value = tb_proj_projectnaam.Text; 
        proj_naam.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;   
        plaats.Value = tb_proj_plaats.Text; 
        plaats.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input; 
        opdrachtgever.Value = cb_proj_opdrachtgever.SelectedValue; 
        opdrachtgever.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
        status.Value = cb_proj_status.SelectedValue; 
        status.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
        proj_id.Value = id; 
        proj_id.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;                    
        break;                 
    case 2:
        stopro = "new_bedrijf";                     
    // etc.
}
```

Comment: I think i'm forced to do it the other way because I need to define the sqlcommand command first with the right string for the right stored procedure and then i can call commandparameter.add. or Is there another way? I would like to avoid defining command1, command2 command3 etc if its possible

Comment: @Daanvl: you can create your `SqlCommand` before the switch statement without any issues.